# Angular check parameter

Tags: angularjs

My code:

/**
 * Created by maki1234 on 14.03.16.
 */

```
angular.module('admin', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/all.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/details/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
            controller: 'detailsController',
            resolve: {
                id: function ($route, $q) {
                     var q = $q.defer();
                     var id = parseInt($route.current.params.id, 10);
                     if (!isNaN(id)) {
                        q.resolve(id);
                     } else {
                        q.reject('Param Id must be a number!');
                     }
                     return q.promise;
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
})
.controller('mainController', function () {

})
.controller('detailsController', function ($scope, $location, id, $log) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
        $scope.error = rejection;
    });

    $log.info($scope.error);
});
```

My problem is: This code works but when ID is numeric, but when it's a string controller doesn't log anything in console. Any suggestion? (when id is numeric in console i see undefined - it's good i think)

Comment: The `$routeChangeError` listener won't be defined unless there is a valid value

Comment: Yes, so when id is numeric undefined is ok but when id isn't numeric it should be log in the console but console is clear without any error.

Comment: In other words: with an invalid value, the `detailsController` will not be called and the `$routeChangeError` listener will not be defined. You need to add the listener code before calling the `detailsController` (e.g. in your `mainController` on `$rootScope`). Can you provide the view?

Comment: Look at the new updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

app.js

```
angular.module('admin', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/all.html',
        })
        .when('/details/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
            controller: 'detailsController',
            resolve: {
                'id': function ($route, $q) {
                        var q = $q.defer();
                        var id = parseInt($route.current.params.id, 10);
                        if (!isNaN(id)) {
                            q.resolve(id);
                        } else {
                            q.reject('Param id must be a number!');
                        }
                        return q.promise;
                    }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
})
.controller('mainController', function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
        $rootScope.error = rejection;
    });
})
.controller('detailsController', function ($scope, id) {
    $scope.id = id;
});
```

index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="mainController" ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

details.html

```
<h3>{{id}}</h3>

<h3>{{error}}</h3>
```

The problem is when I have valid url id is printed on the screen, but when I change id to bad value on the screen I see printed id and the error (it seems that $scope.id is saved and it's all time in memory). Second problem is when I have for example bad url I see error on the screen but when I press F5 and the page "reload" route doesn't change so i see white screen without any error (because route is the same and routeChangeError event isn't fired...).